# Different layout for angular2 login page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have a normal layout with a tool- and sidebar for all my pages, but they should not be visible when the user goes to the login or register page. In AngularJS it was easy with ui-router to include a route before all other pages where you could define a layout.

But how to do it in Angular2 with the native router? Should I use `ngIf`to display the tool- and sidebar or is there a better way?

Comment: I am stucked in the same situation. Please let me know if you have find the solution.

Comment: can you post your code snippets and what version of angular 2 you are using?

Comment: found a good way to manage it.

Comment: @mimo, can you share the way you have found?

Comment: @Dima, I posted the answer to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with the `children` attribute of a route:

```
export const routes:RouterConfig = [
  //includes the login and registration route
  ...userRoutes,
  {
    path: '',
    //checks if the user is logged in
    canActivate: [Auth],
    //only contains a <route-outlet />
    component: LayoutComponent,
    //routes like /dashboard will only accessible when Auth returns true
    children: [
      //all children are 'protected'
      ...modulRoutes,
      ...dashboardRoutes,
    ]
  },
  //404 handling
  ...errorRoutes
];
```

I used the 3.0 router of angular2